# WPF: Bind Listbox with multiple selected Item

Tags: c#, wpf

I am Integrating my application to WPF , in my code i used `ListBox.SetSelected(i, true);` to Display the `Selected Items`, Its works fine in `Window Application`, But it is not working with `WPF`. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to set `Selection mode` of that `List box`. then add items in selected item. as shown below.

```
listBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple;
listBox.SelectedItems.Add(seltectedItem1);
listBox.SelectedItems.Add(seltectedItem2);
```